# JNI and Android... UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

Man... this bug has got me down.

Logcat:

```
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8819)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at com.example.viewer.Viewer.denoiseSlice(Viewer.java:170)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     ... 12 more
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: RicianDenoise
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     at com.example.viewer.Viewer.RicianDenoise(Native Method)
01-29 22:25:00.293: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27386):     ... 16 more
```

Loading the Library and declaring it:

```
    public native void RicianDenoise(int w, int h, int p, 
        short [] s_noised_slice, double [] d_noised_slice, 
        short [] s_denoised_slice, double [] d_denoised_slice);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("denoise");
    }
```

C Function:

```
void 
Java_com_example_viewer_Viewer_RicianDenoise (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jint M, 
                                              jint N, jint P, jshort * s_noised_slice,
                                              jdouble * d_noised_slice, 
                                              jshort * s_denoised_slice, 
                                              jdouble * d_denoised_slice) {
    /* ... */
}
```

I ran

> ndk-build -B -C [project]/jni

and I can't get anything to work. Any suggestions, or experience with this issue? The invocation line in the logcat is me just trying to call the function, btw.  Thank you... please be my hero :(

Comment: Once again, I have no idea how I made it work. Unfortunately, the function just makes the Activity quit with no error message... so here we go off to discover another bug :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in java do not translate into array type pointers in C/C++, in JNI
Use this scheme on the native side to declare your arrays:
for double[] use jdoubleArray
for short[] use jshortArray

Comment: Discovered this later on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does your library use other C/C++ libraries and are those reachable using the system path?

Comment: <math.h>, <string.h>, <stdlib.h>, <stdio.h>, <jni.h> ... i'd think so?